# Editing data into SQL with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this method for Editing data but I don't know how to write the code... Until now I have this which I don't really understand and I have an error in it. It says `incorrect syntax near '('`.

```
        public void EditMember(Member member)
        {
            string Name = member.Name;
            string Surname = member.Surname;
            string EntryDate = member.EntryDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
            string Status = member.Status;

            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(
                "UPDATE Members SET (Name, Surname, EntryDate) VALUES('" + Name + "','" + Surname + "','" + EntryDate + "')' WHERE'(' Id '='" + member.Id + "')",
                sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
```

The problem is when I start to write `WHERE`

Help please.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: always ALWAYS use parameterized queries and DON'T use dynamic SQL. Read up on it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please read all of this answer, not just the first part**

There are multiple issues here. The most *immediate* problem is here:

```
"')' WHERE'('
```

That's acting as if you're trying to quote the bracket. That "should" be:

```
"') WHERE ('
```

At that point it would look like a valid (but bad) `INSERT` command... but your use of `VALUES` which doesn't look like it's a valid way of updating in T-SQL anyway.

However, you shouldn't use this approach at all. It's error-prone, hard to read, and most importantly prone to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Instead, you should use parameterized SQL:

```
string sql = @"UPDATE Members
               SET Name = @Name, Surname = @Surname, EntryDate = @EntryDate
               WHERE Id = @Id";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = member.Name;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = member.Surname;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EntryDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = member.EntryDate;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = member.Id;
        int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // TODO: Work out what to do if rows isn't 1
    }
}
```

(With adjustments for the appropriate data types, of course.)

Comment: @marc_s: Yup, was editing for that. (I'd appreciate it if you'd check the update though :)

Comment: Looks much better now, indeed ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for an update statement is

```
  "UPDATE Members SET Name = @name, Surname = @surname, EntryDate = @date WHERE id=@id"
```

Said that, you should use parameterized query like this

```
    public void EditMember(Member member)
    {
        string Name = member.Name;
        string Surname = member.Surname;
        string EntryDate = member.EntryDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
        string Status = member.Status;

        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Members SET Name = @name, Surname = @surname, " + 
                         "EntryDate = @date " + 
                         "WHERE Id = @id", sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Name);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", Surname);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", EntryDate);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Status);
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Close();
```

As a side note, keep in mind that AddWithValue is a simple way to add parameters to you query, but if the perfomance of this query is critical it is better to use a fully defined parameter with the datatype that matches exactly your database column's type and with the exact size.

Answer (score 1):

You should ***NEVER EVER*** concatenate together your SQL statements with user input.

Instead : use **parametrized queries** - they're easy to use, avoid SQL injection, and improve performance.

Try code something like this:

```
string updateStmt = "UPDATE dbo.Members SET Name = @Name, Surname = @Surname, EntryDate = @EntryDate WHERE Id = @ID";

sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(updateStmt, sqlConnection);

sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = name;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = surname;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@EntryDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = entrydate;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = member.Id;

sqlConnection.Open();
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from around the `WHERE` and you should be fine. Please heed the warnings given in the comments about SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has syntax error for update and also [SQLInjection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) issue.

You need to pass parameters to update query rather than passing direct values.

It should be as follows:

```
public void EditMember(Member member)
{
    string Name = member.Name;
    string Surname = member.Surname;
    string EntryDate = member.EntryDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
    string Status = member.Status;

    sqlConnection.Open();
    sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Members SET Name=@Name, Surname=@Sirname, EntryDate=@EntryDate WHERE Id = @id", sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.parameters.AddparameterWithValue("@Name",Name);
    sqlCommand.parameters.AddparameterWithValue("@Surname",Surname);
    sqlCommand.parameters.AddparameterWithValue("@EntryDate",EntryDate);
    sqlCommand.parameters.AddparameterWithValue("@Id",Id);
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit the post to make correct answer:

i.e. you don't need brackets in where clause. And yes the better query is

```
  "UPDATE Members SET Name=@Name, Surname=@Surname, EntryDate=@EntryDate WHERE  Id=@ID"
```

and then you add @Name, @Surname, .. etc through parameter of command object.

Comment: This syntax `UPDATE Members SET (Name, Surname, EntryDate) VALUES(@Name,@Surname,@EntryDate) ` is **not** valid in SQL Server ...

Comment: This mixes the syntaxes of INSERT and UPDATE statements!

Comment: I am sorry about syntax, I use MYSql and SqlServer a like and forgot the database in question is SQL Server, the above syntax is however correct in MySql Database server. Thank for correction.